# putty ssh can't connect - not supported authentication methods

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, mobaxterm

i get this error : [image]

when i try to log on to my azure instance via ssh keys, when i used the same key via MobaXterm i am able to connect , the key was generate via Linux `ssh-keygen` and is RSA 2048 bit that start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` how can i configure putty to work with this key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your key is in PEM format, which is also the same as the (old) OpenSSH private key format.

Use PuTTYgen to "import" the key through the menu, then use "Save private key" to convert it to .PPK format (which is the only format PuTTY understands natively).

Once converted, you can either open the .PPK file to load it into Pageant (i.e. hold it in memory for all PuTTY/WinSCP connections), or specify its path in PuTTY's "SSH → Authentication" settings.